# ConstraintLayout - Spead horizontally with weight 1, ratio vertically

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I am trying to make 2 views chain horizontally, so they both take `50%` of screen and make their height same as width so they are square. Currently I have this, which doesn't seem to work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/a"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#F00"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/b"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/b"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#0F0"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/a"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silambarasan's answer didn't actually do what I wanted to do but his use of Guideline helped me hint helped me get the right answer

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/mid_guide"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.50" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/a"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#F00"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/mid_guide"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/b"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#0F0"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/mid_guide"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.50" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/view2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="#F00"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="#0F0"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

and the result layout will be...

[image: result]